# ifstream on different dir

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

First, yes, i have searched through sof and google, and all i could find was about using double slashes, but that didin't do the trick, so i'm asking, what i'm doing wrong.

I have a test file called testing.txt on my C drive. (C:/testing.txt)

The code i use is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    ifstream failas;
    failas.open("C:\\testing.txt");
    if (!failas)
    {
        cout<<"not today, baby"<<endl;
    }
    else cout<<"yeah, baby, it's open"<<endl;
    string line;
    getline(failas,line);
    cout<<line;
    failas.close();


    return 0;

}
```

Tried all types of slashes. ( \ // \ / / /\ )
( the program is far away in C disk )
Thanks!

[EDIT]:
Screenshot of folders
http://i48.tinypic.com/5xmt86.png

Comment: If the file exists, your program, as written in the question, should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Joachim. I have uploaded an screenshot of folder. http://i48.tinypic.com/5xmt86.png the program says "not today, baby".

Comment: Maybe this is a privilage issue. Maybe you don't have `read access to C:\\testing.txt`. Since the file in directly in C: this is very probable

Comment: moving to different directory did the trick. Strange, didn't knew that windows protects C disk. Thanks, stardust_!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is a privilege issue. I have faced it too. 
Temporary workaround would be to add one more indirection.
create a folder in C drive and put the file inside it. 
Change the path. It should work fine.